# How to set 2nd div's left and top based on first div by CSS only

Tags: html, css

I could position two div one after one.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
#inner1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
#inner2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="inner1">First One</div>
  <div id="inner2">Second One</div>
</div>
```

but the things which I could not do is to set 2nd div left and top based on first div.

I want to `set 2nd div top = 1st div height + 20 px by CSS` not by JavaScript

same way I want to `set 2nd div left = 1st div left by CSS` not by JavaScript

is it possible by css only which works in old browser too.

discuss with sample code if possible. thanks

Comment: so your saying whatever the second div is you want to be exactly like first div?

Comment: _2nd div left = 1st div left_ they have already the same left value (0) - _2nd div top = 1st div height + 20 px_ a simple margin-top:20px to the 2nd div would solve?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't refer to other element computed style using css only!**

But

There are many tricks to accomplish the behavior you are looking for using css only

Example 1 - [using the margin property](https://jsfiddle.net/7mwy0q9y/)

```
#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto; 
    width:auto;
}
#inner1{
  float:left; 
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
#inner2{
  margin-top:-200px; //we decrease the the top margin with the height of the pervius element
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left; 
  clear: left;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Example 2 - [using the position property](https://jsfiddle.net/wdsh5401/)

```
#wrapper{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto; 
    width:auto;
    position:relative; //makeing the wrapper "relative"
}

#inner1{
  position:absolute; // setting position absolute
  top:0;             // and top 0 so they have the same top
  float:left; 
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}
#inner2{
  position:absolute; // setting position absolute
  top:0;             // and top 0 so they have the same top
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  float:left; 
  clear: left;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Comment: i do not want to hard code `margin-top:-200px` for #inner2. any other solution exist.

Comment: your second one is totally different because they coming next to each other but i want one after another.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use margin-top for the second div?

```
#inner2{
   margin-top: 20px;
}
```

you can no longer use float then.